# How do I merge two accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, duplicate-accounts

I logged in today with my Launch Pad ID thinking it was the correct Open ID account. Lo and behold, I created a new user by mistake. Is there any way I can merge the two?

https://askubuntu.com/users/74557/enrique

https://askubuntu.com/users/146029/user146029

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can you still access your older account?  If so, head to the "[Merge User Profiles](https://askubuntu.com/help/user-merge)" page, and follow the instructions.

If that doesn't work, you can submit this request to Stack Exchange from this page: https://askubuntu.com/help/other